# Help for suspending session or hibernating

Tags: suspend, power-management, hibernate

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I want to put the system in suspend or hibernate mode and I have activated hibernation. When I do `sudo pm-suspend` or `sudo pm-hibernate`, the system apparently obeys, but when I want to restore the session, the screen freezes after a few seconds.

If I use the system tray do it, it fails.

---

I did what you proposed to me, but it ditn't walk.
It suspends or hibernates.
What concerning the supending; When I want to restore the session, the screen is black and nothing is visible.
For the hibernation It hibernates the sesion but It can't restore it.
 The restoration is random, sometimes, it restores (I think when there are not enough application opened), sometimes, it can't, a strange srceen (an indescriptible color) appears. And then I have to reboot it again.

Nothing goes as I expect.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

16.04 now uses SystemD. Try this and see if it works even after waking:

1. Reboot your system and wait for it to settle.  This is to get out of the uncertain state you mentioned above, start clean.
2. Choose one of the the following commands and try it, no need for sudo.  I recommend suspend first as it is supported 99% of the time by the hardware:

SUSPEND:

```
systemctl suspend
```

HIBERNATE:

```
systemctl hibernate
```

Here's the man webpage for systemctl:  https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html